# React event in parent component and run a function from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items in my `Main` component. It has a child component called `Posts`. The `Posts` component contains a fetch function that retrieves new data when the user scrolls down through the items. The `Main` component also includes a search bar with a filter and search button. I click this button in the `Main` component, but what I want is that this button runs fetch function inside `Posts` component.

The only way I find is to put the fetch function inside parent `Main` and pass it down to `Posts`. However, this way my `Main` will soon be full of unmanageable code? What is common practice for such tasks and how could I upgrade my code?

Main:

```
//...
function Main({posts, authToken, authTokenType, username, userId}) {
//...
     return (
        <div>
        <Posts 
          authToken={authToken}
          authTokenType={authTokenType}
          username={username}
        />
```

Posts:

```
//...
function Posts({authToken,authTokenType, username}) {
//...
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const fetchData = () => {
        fetch(BASE_URL + `post/all?page=${page}`)
        //...
        return(
          <div>
              <InfiniteScroll
               dataLength={posts.length}
               next={fetchData}
               hasMore={hasMore}
               loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
             >
              <Row>
              {posts.map((post, index) => (
                 <Col lg={3}>
                 <Post
                 post = {post}
                 authToken={authToken}
                 authTokenType={authTokenType}
                 username={username}
                 /> </Col>
          ))}</Row>
        </InfiniteScroll>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Post component, you can add:

```
useEffect(() => {
  doFetch(); // Run the fetch function
}, [props.triggerFetch]);
```

And i your Main, add this attribute:

```
<Post
   triggerFetch={doTriggerFetch}
   post = {post}
   authToken={authToken}
   authTokenType={authTokenType}
   username={username}
/>
```

When you update `doTriggerFetch` in the Main component, it will execute the `doFetch` function in the `Post` component.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the best solution but you could use the useImperativeHandle hook and forwardRef:

```js
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    log() {
      console.log("child function");
    }
  }));

  return <h1>Child</h1>;
});
```

```
const Parent = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={() => ref.current.log()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```